# What is the history of ‘history’?

Tags: etymology

The meaning of history is clear. That which is in the past. Is the cultural use of the word ‘history’ a corrupted ‘yesterday/gisteren/gestern’ descriptive for ‘the day before the stars (compare Dutch Gesternte Dag (stars day)) Or is it a cognate of ‘yesterday’?

And how does the word ‘future’ relate to ‘tomorrow’? It seems cognate with a phrase ‘vue terre’ (earth view) as if relating to someone seeing coming towards* you. It seems both words relate to darkness (stars-history) and light on earth (vue-terre-future). *Dutch ‘toekomst’ (compounded toward-coming)

Just some ideas I have, but are there answers by historians, philosophers or linguists about this issue?

Comment: Migrate to linguistics? There’s no historical or historiographic content.

Comment: Made-up etymologies like this really makes me cringe, honestly. These are obviously words of Latin origin, and if it's not obvious, even a cursory look at Wiktionary can make it obvious in a second. Sometimes etymology is unclear enough that it has to be speculated about and researched in detail; sometimes, it's there on any dictionary. This is one of the latter cases, and that's why I downvoted this question.

Comment: I'm not quite seeing the semantic connection between "earth view" and "future"; surely you can see the earth at any time?

Comment: The horizon in some languages translates to ‘maximum view’. It is about what on earth you can see coming used in the context of time what is to come. German Zukunft and Dutch toekomst show the same relation I guess.

Comment: @Draconis, you wrote; “I'm not quite seeing the semantic connection between "earth view" and "future"; surely you can see the earth at any time?” Finisterre (the end of the earth) is also often interpreted as the ending of the existence of the world (in Armageddon) and fantasised upon or Vue terre (view earth) could literally looking down at the earth but in relation to time the horizon (end of the view of earth) is descriptive for where to look. It is relating to an idea as far as semantics is concerned.

Comment: @Ajagar You need to rein in your tone, and have a read of the [code of conduct](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/conduct).

Comment: If you want to ask about the etymology of the word 'history', please do so at the [english.se] site.

Comment: @Ajagar You need to appreciate that word histories — which are termed “etymologies” — are not simple narratives or guesswork. One isn’t just as good or true as another. Words, like animals, leave a fossil record. We can *see* words evolve over time in the artifacts our predecessors left behind. Etymologies are based on this historical record. We can *see* “history” came to English from Greek via Latin. We can *see* its intermediate forms, each connected to the last. Any speculation about a word’s origins needs to be and is tested against the extant *facts*. Is this troublesome to you?

Comment: @Dan; what I am saying is that what may be traced is the writing down of the meaning history in different languages. The intermediates as you say could be dialects and other languages not showing an Exodus of tge Greek word but an emergence of the word in writing. It seems that History has an anagram in Old German ‘Er weyd es’ and French ‘il sait voir’ (he knows to see) have anagrammic relations with l'histoire. Because of that one could argue that the phrases that compound to the word history are older than the term history. Just this possibility alone if not researched well can undermine...

Comment: ...the assumption that a word became a loan of a loan of a loan. But these methods are not based on the written evidence only but on the spoken evidence, on human behaviour patterns and the need to describe that caused many compounds from descriptive phrases. As long as those options are not proper researched (and therefor I ask) it is impossible to claim a family tree from Greek to English based on written evidence alone. I am saying reality is more difficult than the model used at the moment. But all I get if I ask such things (not even stating) is downvotes. That means my curiosity and ...

Comment: ...honoust goes at making methods better is killing my reputation here as if I am undermining Stack Exchange. And it does not help if people put words in my mouth or insinuate. I appreciate a dialogue in the comments based on content. So if history already existed as a phrase in other languages it could have become a compound after the Greek or Latin example but it would not stem from it. If there is one model and it is swallowed because there is nothing better. Linguistics is in its infant shoes regarding language.

Comment: History is very young. If parallel processes are excluded from the model, it is becoming a religion.

Comment: We do not have any evidence of oral history. We only have written history, by definition. Any hypotheses based on "oral usage" or verbalization are pure, unadorned speculation, and their credibility is weighted by this inadequacy. Speculation based on *anagramming* is merely the first step into apologetics for numerology. That is not how words are formed and has no bearing on the word's, or any word's, etymology. Etymology is a science, and science is driven and judged by adduction of *evidence*. All the evidence we have concludes that the etymology of history is just how Draconis has it.

Comment: If you open your mouth to speak you provide evidence. That is experience based and nurtured but it is still evidence. Analogies are a prehistoric way to produce antonyms avant la lettre. It is not always the case as there are other methods too to create antonyms. And it is not restricted to antonyms. But I cant explain 7 years of work here. And because evidence based science ignores experience based science, the anthroposofical funtions of speech and the use of methods such as anagrams are underestemated. And what is worse, there are people like you defending only the evidence based method.

Comment: If that speech is recorded so others many analyze it, it is evidence. If it is not recorded, and can't be independently analyzed, it is not evidence. It is anecdote at best, falsification at worst. It is not "people like me" who defending the evidence-based method of science. That is the *definition* of science. It is the *very thing*, the *critical insight*, that distinguishes science from its fuzzier and significantly less successful predecessors. Science recognizes *reality* as th ultimate filter. If you haven't already, it would more than repay your time to read Popper, or a summary of him

Comment: Why could a group of people not decide to call a dwarf a dwarf (Zwerg/Dwerg in German/Dutch) after the anagram Growth/Gross/Groot) which is its antonym? Why Day/Tag/Dag and Light/(Licht); leg/less and ciel (as sole and soul); fruit/Frucht vs druif/traub; fall and lift/elevate. I could go on for ages. It is unbelievable to say this is only coincidence or imagination. No it is easy to explain scientifically but it is not given a chance because the atestation model is holy.

Comment: Because the actual evidence, the thing we can inspect, the thing we can test any such arbitrary theory against, says otherwise. It is precisely because we can invent infinite theories ("go on for ages"), but only a finite number are true, that we need a method for identifying the correct ones, and the only way to do that is to interrogate reality. Reality gets to decide: we do not.  If you want to argue about the philosophy of empiricism, you'll have to find another venue. This will be my last comment in this thread.

Comment: Einstein; “condamnation without investigation is the height of ignorance.” We as a worldly community owe it to science to investigate all.

Comment: Tanks Dan. I agree, but the historical linguistic method is only 50% of reality. Hawkins theories should be applied to linguistics as well but I think the scientific community may not be ready for it yet. It is my last too here. Because of the downvotes I can not chat (just so anyone wanting to know more knows that path is sealed). My reputation in History Exchange is not crushed by the fosil records. Find me there and invite for chat.

Comment: Your reputation wouldn't be taking such a hit if you asked questions in the proper place - this is off-topic at History and it's off-topic here.

Comment: Ajagar, this and your other questions show a consistent preference for speculation that runs counter to well-established history and semantic and phonological methodology, then stonewalling when you're told this. You're free to entertain yourself this way, but it'll never receive a warm welcome on this site. You should find another forum if you want people to discuss it with you as a serious subject.

Comment: Thanks for the insights. My ideas do not fit mainstream linguistics. That means I won’t bother anyone with ‘speculative’ questions anymore.

Answer (score 11):

The word "history" comes (via French) from the Latin *historia*, from Greek *historía*, "narration". In Greek this goes back to the verb *historé-* "research", from the noun *histōr* "expert", from earlier *wistōr*, which probably goes back to PIE **w-yd-* "see, know" (so cognate with German *Wissen*, English "wise", and Latin derivatives like "vision").

(The linguistic processes involved are quite well-attested: initial *w* tends to turn into *h* or disappear in Ancient Greek; the ending *-st-* is like English "-ist"; *-ds-* turns into *-s-*.)

"Yesterday" on the other hand seems to go all the way back to the PIE word for, well, "yesterday". Cognates include German *Gestern* and Latin *hesternus*.

(Again, the linguistic processes are well-attested: Old English turned *g* into *y* next to front vowels, for example, which is why we see English "e**y**e" next to German *Au**g**e*.)

"Future" comes from Latin *futūr-*, which is the future participle of the verb for "to be", from the PIE root for "to become". This PIE root also led to the forms of English "to be" that start with a letter B: be, been, being.

(And once again, the phonological processes here are quite solidly attested: the sound that PIE scholars call **bʰ* turned into *f* at the beginning of words in Latin, but turned into *b* in Germanic languages like English.)

Comment: As for that German word `Gestern`, which has the prefix `ge-`. That prefix also was attested in Old and Middle English, and Chaucer uses `y-`. Obviously the modern English word has carried that forward. I'm just surprised that Latin `hesternus` is considered cognate here. Does Latin have some history of a (semi-)productive prefix `he-`?

Comment: @Wilson. No, "gestern, yesterday" do not have the prefix ge. Yes, these words are cognate with Latin hesternus. https://www.dwds.de/wb/gestern

Comment: The use of “historia” to mean “an account of past events” is probably on the basis of the first sentence of Herodotus’s book, where he refers to his “istoriē” (thus in Ionic), i.e. “investigation”. The h- of the Attic form is apparently secondary.

Comment: Indeed re *gestern* ... Seeing a *ge-* where there is none leads to the wrong pronunciation :)